# Reassigning value using a CASE statement - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

here is a simple example of how my return data is structured:

```
id | cat id | value | reverse
1  | 1      | 5     | false
2  | 1      | 5     | false
3  | 2      | 2     | true
4  | 2      | 1     | false
5  | 1      | 3     | true
```

In the sql statement below, I am trying to get the count for each `value` type group by `value` column.  If the `reverse` column is true, I need to reverse the scale.  So the scale would be:

```
5 = 1
4 = 2
3 = 3
2 = 4
1 = 5
```

I tried the following SQL statement, but it seems not to be applying the reverse scale to the count, it is just ignoring the reverse flag all together:

```
select value, count(
case reverse
    WHEN false THEN 
        CASE value
        WHEN '5' THEN '1'
        WHEN '4' THEN '2'
        WHEN '3' THEN '3'
        WHEN '2' THEN '4'
        WHEN '1' THEN '5'

    END
    ELSE value
END
)
from table1
group by value
```

What I am doing wrong?  How do I apply the reverse logic to count the reverse question value to the correct value?

Comment: Isn't value an integer?

Comment: It is a varchar but I can cast to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I may be misunderstanding; if so I apologize. But my understanding is that you're wanting to get the counts by an absolute value....so if I have five rows that had a value of 1 and five rows that had a value of 5 (reversed), I would want to show a count of ten for value of 1.

Assuming that's the case and that you have a string instead of an int (but that the values are all integers and not something more complicated:

```
    ;WITH reversed AS 
    (
        SELECT id, 
            [cat id], 
            CASE WHEN [reverse] = 1 THEN 6 - CAST([value] AS INT) 
                ELSE CAST([value] AS INT) END AS [calcValue]
        FROM table1
    )
    SELECT calcValue, COUNT(id) AS counts
    FROM reversed
    GROUP BY calcValue;
```

Part of the problem with the original calculation is that you're not doing anything with the original value before grouping it, you're just taking the count of the case statement. The `COUNT()` won't be different if the values within it are different, so long as the values aren't `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with data as ( 
  select * from ( values
    (1,1,5,'false'),
    (2,1,5,'false'),
    (3,2,2,'true'),
    (4,2,1,'false'),
    (5,1,3,'true')
    ) data(id,cat,value,reverse)
) 
select 
  id,
  cat,
  value = case when reverse='false' then value else 6-value end
from data
```

returning this:

```
id          cat         value
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           5
2           1           5
3           2           4
4           2           1
5           1           3
```